# I have following two MySQL queries and i want to execute it inside one procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join

Following query returns 10 rows of recipe id's i wants to pass first query's output which is of 10 rows to the second query and display the output of both the queries inside a procedure.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT 
    p.ID as recipe_ID,
    p.post_title as recipe_title,
    p.post_date as modified_date,
    p.post_name as recipe_url,
    CASE WHEN s.total_count THEN s.total_count ELSE 0 END as total_like_count,
    CASE WHEN c.bookmark=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bookmark_status,
    CASE WHEN c.like_status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as like_status,
    CASE WHEN pm.meta_value=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as unlock_status

FROM
    posts p
LEFT JOIN social_val s on(p.ID=s.post_id)
LEFT JOIN social_status_connection as c on(p.ID=c.post_id AND c.user_id=1)
LEFT JOIN postmeta pm on(p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_value=1 AND pm.meta_key='recipe_lock'),
term_relationships as t, term_taxonomy tt
WHERE
  p.post_type = 'recipe'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'   
    and p.ID = t.object_id
    and tt.term_id = 1279
    and t.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id     

ORDER BY modified_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

**Query 2**
Below query is self join which generates image of above particular recipe id.

```
SELECT 
    p.guid as recipeImageURL
FROM
    posts p,
    posts m
where
    p.post_type = 'attachment'
        AND p.post_parent = m.ID
        AND m.ID = ID ORDER BY p.post_modified DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: so your question is ... "write a procedure" ???

Comment: I have created separate procedure for above queries one for recipe details and one for image of particular recipe.My question is how to pass parameter of 1st query to 2nd query inside one procedure..is it possible?

Comment: Possible... added answer

Comment: Why don't you combine the two queries into one?

Comment: because in WHERE clause  p.post_type = 'recipe' AND p.post_status = 'publish' this condition is must. and in second query i have to use self join in that post_type='attachment' which return image url......I dont want to use sub query which will slow down 1st query....is there any other alternative using JOIN's?

Comment: @ypercube : I tried with following sub query:

Comment: it takes average 5 seconds to execute during pick hours...How can i make more efficient:
SELECT p.ID as recipe_ID    ,
(SELECT m.guid  FROM  dattu_posts m   where   m.post_type = 'attachment'  AND m.post_parent = p.ID  ORDER BY m.post_modified DESC   LIMIT 1) as img  FROM  ...
      WHERE  ...  ORDER BY modified_date DESC

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop over the output of one query to another you can use [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html).

For eg, in this stored routine to [find in all tables databases](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/search-through-all-databases-tables-columns-in-mysql) we have looped over:

```
DECLARE table_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ...
OPEN table_cur;
table_loop:LOOP
...code...
END LOOP;
CLOSE table_cur;
```

So in your case declare cursor for first query and loop over each recipeid.

Comment: Try to do it without a cursor.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with CURSOR inside single procedure:

**First Procedure:** Display recipe details

BEGIN
SELECT 
                    p.ID as recipe_ID,
                      p.post_title as recipe_title,
                      p.post_date as modified_date,
                      p.post_name as recipe_url,
                      CASE WHEN s.total_count THEN s.total_count ELSE 0 END as total_like_count,
                      CASE WHEN c.bookmark=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bookmark_status,
                      CASE WHEN c.like_status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as like_status,
                      CASE WHEN pm.meta_value=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as unlock_status

```
              FROM
                  posts p
              LEFT JOIN social_val s on(p.ID=s.post_id)
              LEFT JOIN social_status_connection as c on(p.ID=c.post_id AND c.user_id=userid)
              LEFT JOIN postmeta pm on(p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_value=1 AND pm.meta_key='recipe_lock'),
              term_relationships as t, term_taxonomy tt
              WHERE
                p.post_type = 'recipe'
                  AND p.post_status = 'publish'   
                  and p.ID = t.object_id
                  and tt.term_id =termid
                  and t.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id        
               ORDER BY modified_date DESC
                LIMIT offset , 5;
```

CALL recipe_list(userid,termid,offset); //calling second procedure for image
END

**Second Procedure: (For recipe images)**
BEGIN 
        DECLARE post_id int DEFAULT 0;

-- declare cursor for recipe_image_cursor
 DEClARE recipe_image_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 
p.ID as recipe_ID
FROM
posts p
LEFT JOIN social_share_counts s on(p.ID=s.post_id)
LEFT JOIN social_status_connection as c on(p.ID=c.post_id AND c.user_id=1)
LEFT JOIN postmeta pm on(p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_value=1 AND pm.meta_key='recipe_lock'),
term_relationships as t, term_taxonomy tt
WHERE
p.post_type = 'recipe'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
and p.ID = t.object_id
and tt.term_id = 1279
and t.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id
LIMIT 0 , 10;

OPEN recipe_image_cursor;

get_image: LOOP

FETCH recipe_image_cursor INTO post_id;

--Display Results
SELECT 
                         p.guid as recipeImageURL
                        FROM
                            posts p,
                            posts m
                        where
                            p.post_type = 'attachment'
                                AND p.post_parent = m.ID
                                AND m.ID = post_id ORDER BY p.post_modified DESC
                        LIMIT 1; 
 END LOOP get_image; 
 CLOSE recipe_image_cursor;
END

How can i display result of cursor in column format..is it possible? or which is the better way?..i am new with procedures and cursor